# ActionScript3 -how can I detect mouse events on hidden objects(stacked Movie Clips)

Tags: flash, actionscript, mouseevent, movieclip, stacked

I am currently working on an AS3/Flash CS5.5 project.
I have two movieclips, one above the other(different layers, **same coordinates** on stage).
My problem is simple: the 'outer' MovieClip(on the level above) 'hides', from a logical point of view, the 'internal' MovieClip.
Thus, even if I try to manage Mouse Events on hidden MovieClip, these events will not be never fired!
I need a way to detect - for example - MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE on *internal*/hidden MovieClip.
Thanks

IT

Comment: What do you mean by transparent clip?
I hope you do not intend Alpha-0 MovieClips
I need some kind of "logically-transparent" MovieClips instead.
Please note I am _not_ an AS3 developer.
Thanks
IT

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just place another transparent clip responsible for all mouse interactions above everything else and have that as a front controller that will dispatch messages to the rest of your system?

Either that or look into bubbling the event programmatically so on MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE call the trigger for that same event on the bellow clip.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
outerMC.mouseEnabled = false;
outerMC.mouseChildren = false;
```

This way the 'outer' (top) object won't receive any mouse events and will let them reach the bottom object...